# How to add several options for user input in an if statement

Tags: javascript, html, user-input

I'm trying to make a code where you can get a letter grade from a percentage grade. The grading scale is printed at the top of the code. Then, I made a button where when you click it, it prompts the suer to input their percentage grade. Im trying to make it so if the user inputs, for example, 93 the code will tell them they have an A. Im trying to do this for all values of 100-90 for an A, 89-80 for a B, 79-70 for a C, 69-60 for a D, 59-50 for an E, and anything less than 50 for an F. I have the code for the grade scale and I started the function for the function that will give the user their letter grade, but cannot figure out how to have more than one value in the if statement.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var q1 = prompt("Please enter your percentage grade: ");
  if (q1 <= 100 && grade > 90) {
    alert("You have an A");
  }
  if (q1 <= 89 && grade > 80) {
    alert("You have a B");
  }
  if (q1 <= 79 && grade > 70) {
    alert("You have a C");
  }
  if (q1 <= 69 && grade > 60) {
    alert("You have a D");
  }
  if (q1 <= 59 && grade > 50) {
    alert("You have an E");
  }
  if (q1 > 50) {
    alert("You have an F");
  } else {
    alert("Broken")
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <h1>Grade Scale</h1>
  <p>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>A</th>
        <th>B</th>
        <th>C</th>
        <th>D</th>
        <th>E</th>
        <th>F</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>100-90</td>
        <td>89-80</td>
        <td>79-70</td>
        <td>69-60</td>
        <td>59-50</td>
        <td>
          < 50</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </p>

  <p2>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Click Here To See Your Conversion!</button>
  </p2>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure that there are `<p1>` and `<p2>` tags in the HTML5 specification?

Comment: AND operator  `if (grade <= 100 && grade > 90) { A...` means: *"if the grade is less than or equal to 100 AND grade is greater than 90 ..."*

Comment: p1 and p2 is not a html tag. just use `<p> </p>` like this for paragraphs.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with `if - else` statements. This will ensure that only one condition matches for all the `if` blocks - and you also need just a single condition for each `if` statement:

```html
<p>   
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Click Here To See Your Conversion!</button>
</p>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var grade = prompt("Please enter your percentage grade: ");
  if (grade > 90) {
    alert("You have an A");
  }
  else if (grade > 80){
    alert("You have a B");
  }
  else if (grade > 70){
    alert("You have a C"); 
  }
  else if (grade > 60){
    alert("You have a D");
  }
  else if (grade > 50){
    alert("You have an E");
  }
  else {
    alert("You have an F"); 
  }
}
</script>
```

By the way: please check your variables and use the same name for all (`q1` and `grade` should be the same I guess).

Answer (score 0):

The main issue was that your variables were not named consistently, so I changed them all to q1. Your logic with the `>` conditions was also a bit off, so I changed them so they account for the correct ranges.  Remember, for something like a B, it will be all numbers less than 90 and greater than or equal to 80.  `90 > B >= 80`

Also as others have mentioned `<p1>` and `<p2>` are not proper html tags.  Please use `<p>` instead.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var q1 = prompt("Please enter your percentage grade: ");
  if (q1 <= 100 && q1 >= 90) {
    alert("You have an A");
  }
  else if (q1 < 90 && q1 >= 80) {
    alert("You have a B");
  }
  else if (q1 < 80 && q1 >= 70) {
    alert("You have a C");
  }
  else if (q1 < 70 && q1 >= 60) {
    alert("You have a D");
  }
  else if (q1 < 60 && q1 >= 50) {
    alert("You have an E");
  }
  else if (q1 < 50 && q1 >= 0) {
    alert("You have an F");
  }
  else {
    alert("Broken")
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <h1>
    Grade Scale
  </h1>

  <p>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>A</th>
        <th>B</th>
        <th>C</th>
        <th>D</th>
        <th>E</th>
        <th>F</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>100-90</td>
        <td>89-80</td>
        <td>79-70</td>
        <td>69-60</td>
        <td>59-50</td>
        <td>< 50</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </p>
  
  <p>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Click Here To See Your Conversion!</button>
  </p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not necessary to have two conditions in each if block. The first one is always `true` because of the previous block (see my answer)

Comment: I was trying to follow his original logic and not change the code too much.  And there is still a problem with yours, it doesn't account for answers that are above 100 or less than 0 ("Broken" in the original answer)

Comment: Another thing your answer doesn't account for is when the input is not a number string.  if you include the range for each number then it will guarantee it is actually between the two other numbers and not a string with a correlating higher value.

Comment: You are right, my check does not handle (or validate) all types of input. But why does your code return an "F" for empty inputs or spaces " "?

Comment: You're right too, my answer does not handle all input types either.  I was just trying to help fix OP's code without changing it too much, and his input did account for at least some extraneous input. So that is why I left it as it was, with the range checking.